# How to create a module transition that pushes a view controller and slide another view controller in front?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Sorry if my title is horrible, I'm trying to create a navigation controller that pop like the mail in ios, like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about the previous push? Correct me if im wrong, but you want to first push a VC and after that pop another VC iOS mail like-ish?

Comment: Check my answer below, the push is just a simple push, then in the pushed vc create the smaller one and set it as a child, simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution (thus it might not be the most programmatically correct, im not sure), could be set both ViewController (the one one appearing like mail and the one behind him) inside a parent ViewController and manage their views as you like.

Something I done quickly:

[image]

Both ViewController working, of course you can disable the bottom one and set a gray view over as in your image.

code:

Inside the bottom ViewController create a new NavigationController with the ViewController you want to push and then add it as a child of the first one:

```
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[VcWithNavViewController new]];
[nav.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 500)];
[self addChildViewController:nav];
[self.view addSubview:nav.view];
[nav didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

then simply animate the view of that child into your screen when the time is right:

```
- (void) popViewController {
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [nav.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width, 500)];
} completion:nil];
```

}